# c++ iterating through whole list

Tags: c++, list, logic

I have function that takes in a list for example {10,14,2,4,8}
I then iterate through the whole list and as i am going I divide it by a divisor and then % 2. The loop should keep on running until the divisor is larger then the largest number in the list. A sample output would be;

```
10=0
14=0
2=0
4=0
8=0
```

and then divisor get multiplied by 2 and produces.

```
10=1
14=1
...
```

I am only getting the first part and then it stops. I know my logic is wrong some where.

```
void Splice(std::list<int> list_Original)
{
   int largest_number_in_list=getMax(list_Original);
   int divisor=1;
   std::list<int> new_list;

   for(std::list<int>::iterator i=list_Original.begin();i !=      list_Original.end();i++)
   {
       if(divisor<largest_number_in_list)
       {
           int n=((*i/divisor)%2);
           std::cout<<*i<<"="<<n<<std::endl;
           //new_list.push_back(n);
           divisor=2*divisor;
           //std::cout<<"hihh";
        }

        for(std::list<int>::iterator i=new_list.begin();i!=new_list.end();i++)
        {
            std::cout<<*i<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As for me then I have understood nothing. Can you use the human language?!

Comment: You're doubling the divisor for each number encountered. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes im doing a radix sort and the book provides an example algorithm which i am trying to use "Splice " the list and increment the divisor by divisor = 2*divisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring whatever you're doing with the "new list", you're `for` loop is exiting after it iterates over the list once.  You're also doubling the divisor during every iteration.  You want the check between `divisor` and the largest number to loop around the `for` loop so use a `while`.

```
while (divisor < largest_number_in_list)
{   
    for(std::list<int>::iterator i=list_Original.begin();i !=list_Original.end();i++)
    {
        int n=((*i/divisor)%2);
        std::cout<<*i<<"="<<n<<std::endl;
    }

    divisor=2*divisor;
}
```

Comment: what im trying to do is a radix sort. The list gets divided first by 1 which is the divisor. After wards the list gets divided by 2 because of divisor = 2*divisor and so on 4,6,8,10,12,14.... until the divisor is larger then the biggest number in the list.